# How to tag a friend in any Post generated by a facebook application?

Tags: facebook, post, tags

When we update status in facebook, we can tag a friend in it by issuing a @ symbol and typing the friends name.

Similar to this, I want to tag some friend in a post generated by my facebook application. I have searched in the facebook GRAPH API for the solution but couldn't find it. I have seen some application doing this. Can you please tell me how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article describes how to do it: http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/faq/graphapi/graph_32.html

From the article:

> To have your friend's name to be displayed as a link to his/her user profile when publishing a post via Graph API, you can use the syntax when formatting the message:
>
> ```
> @[{user_id}:1:{name}]
> ```
>
> For example, if you want to publish the message "I had met my old friend XXXX today!" where XXXX will be a link to your friend's profile (with user ID 1234567890), then simply prepare the message as:
>
> ```
> I had met my old friend @[1234567890:1:XXXX] today!
> ```
>
> Then publish it via Graph API as usual.

Comment: XXXX is troubling me. When I fetch my a user's friend list, I fetch it with $facebook->api('/me/friends');

The JSON I get such does not contain the link to the profile page. How can I find the XXXX in such case ?

Comment: It appears that this functionality was disabled at some point, and may not even have been intentionally exposed by Facebook to begin with.

Comment: is there a new way to do this now?